# How to create Sinon Spy wrapper for entire class

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I would like to create a Sinon spy for an entire object/class as opposed to having to write an individual spy for every function/method in it.

So instead of doing this

```
let fooClass = new FooClass();
let fooClassGetDataSpy = sinon.spy(fooClass, 'getData');
let fooClassBarMethodSpy = sinon.spy(fooClass, 'barMethod');
assert(fooClassSpy.getDataFromDb.called);
assert(fooClassSpy.barMethod.called);
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
let fooClassSpy = sinon.spy(FooClass);
// Assume the real `getData` method calls another method called `getDataFromDb`
const result = fooClassSpy.getData();
assert(fooClassSpy.getDataFromDb.called);
assert(fooClassSpy.barMethod.called);
```

So basically I want to retain the real behaviour of all of the methods belonging to a class and at the same time be able to use the Spy API to make assertions against them as if I'd created a spy for each function separately. Any way to accomplish this? I'm using Node 8, ES6 and the latest version of Mocha and Sinon.

Answer (score 2):

For `"sinon": "^7.5.0"`, you can use `sinon.spy(obj)` to

> Spies all the object’s methods.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export class FooClass {
  getData() {
    console.log('getData');
    this.getDataFromDb();
    this.barMethod();
  }
  getDataFromDb() {
    console.log('getDataFromDb');
  }
  barMethod() {
    console.log('barMethod');
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { FooClass } from './';
import sinon, { assert } from 'sinon';

describe('48775401', () => {
  it('should spy all methods of FooClass', () => {
    sinon.spy(FooClass.prototype as any);
    const logSpy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
    const fooClass = new FooClass();
    fooClass.getData();
    assert.calledOnce(fooClass.getData as sinon.SinonSpy);
    assert.calledOnce(fooClass.barMethod as sinon.SinonSpy);
    assert.calledWith(logSpy.firstCall, 'getData');
    assert.calledWith(logSpy.secondCall, 'getDataFromDb');
    assert.calledWith(logSpy.thirdCall, 'barMethod');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  48775401
getData
getDataFromDb
barMethod
    ✓ should spy all methods of FooClass


  1 passing (8ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mongoose5.x-lab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/48775401

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to iterate over the class properties and build out an object of spies like so:

```
function spyOnAllMethods (obj) {
  let spies = {};

  for (var property in obj) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof object[property] === 'function') {
          spies[property] = sinon.spy(obj, property);
      }
  }

  return spies;
}


spyOnAllMethods(FooClass);
```